Producer unable to send message to Kafka Broker
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringKafkaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringKafkaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
    private String ms = "Hello Kafka";
    public void sendMessage(String msg) {
        kafkaTemplate.send("main", msg);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {

   @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
   private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
         return new NewTopic("main", 1, (short) 1);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;
    
        
    public Map<String,Object> producerConfig() {
        Map<String,Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory(){
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(){
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
    
}

application.properties 
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092

When I start the application I am unable to send message to Kafka Broker from Producer. The admin client is unregistered. Please help me to resolve the issue.
The log files is shown below:
Kafka commitId: 5e3c2b738d253ff5
Kafka startTimeMs: 1712071898984
App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered
I wrote a Springboot Kafka integration application to send message from Springboot to Kafka broker but unable to send as it says in the logs unregistered and I can't send message. I want to send message to Kafka broker from Sping boot.

I wonder how it works if you remove all those Spring for Apache Kafka infrastructure beans. The ProducerFactory, KafkaTemplate and KafkaAdmin are auto-configured by Spring Boot. And you indeed don't need that producerConfig bean since everything in Spring Boot is going to be based on the provided application.properties. There is also not need in the spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092 since that value is a default one in Spring Boot.

Can you please elaborate and put the code what you are expecting to make it work. What code is necessary to send the message using SpringBoot.

The minimal working code against local Apache Kafka should be just like this:
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringKafkaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringKafkaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    private String ms = "Hello Kafka";

    public void sendMessage(String msg) {
        kafkaTemplate.send("main", msg);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
         return new NewTopic("main", 1, (short) 1);
    }

}

Not sure where you call that sendMessage(), but it must be used when the whole application context is ready.
